# How to disable payment method on the basis of shipping class of items in cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to disable certain payment methods based on the shipping class of items added in cart.

I have tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'unset_gateway_by_sclass' );

function unset_gateway_by_sclass( $available_gateways ) {
if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;
$unset = false;
$category_ids = array( no-cod );
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'shipping_class' );    
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {        
        if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ids ) ) {
            $unset = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if ( $unset == true ) unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
return $available_gateways;
}
```

This is not working, where am I going wrong in this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'sclass_func', 10, 2 );

function sclass_func( $available_gateways ) {
$shipping_class_target = 1157; 
$in_cart = false;
foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
 if( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
  $in_cart = true;
  break;
 } 
}
if( $in_cart ) {
unset($available_gateways['cod']);
}
return $available_gateways;
}
```